# Restriction map between dual spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Note there is no bounded operator $T : c_0 \rightarrow c_{00}$ such that $T|c_{00}$ is the identity map.

Consider the restriction map given by $F:c_0^*  \rightarrow c_{00}^*$, where $F(f)(x)=f(x)$, for $f \in c_0^*, x \in c_{00}^*$.

I've shown it's well-defined. I'm trying to determine whether it's injective and whether it's surjective.

My intuition is that it's a bijection, as $c_0^*=c_{00}^*=l_1$, when $c_0^* $ and $c_{00}^*$ are under the supremum norm.

But I'm not sure how to construct the proof.

Comment: What have you tried for showing that it is injective? What have you tried for surjective?

Comment: Try to show a more general result: If $L$ is a dense subspace of a normed space $X$ then the restriction map $r: X^*\to L^*$ is bijective. Injectivity uses the fact that a continuous map which vanishes on a dense subset  vanishes everywhere (not even linearity is needed) and for the surjectivity you have to extend every continuous linear functional on $L$ to one on $X$. Either use Hahn-Banach or the extension of *uniformly* continuous maps to completions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(based on the comment from Jochen)

For injectivity,
suppose that $f\in c_0^*$ satisfies $F(f)(x)=0$ for all $x\in c_{00}$.
Then we have $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in c_{00}$,
and since $c_{00}$ is dense in $c_0$ this implies $f=0$.

For surjectivity, suppose that $g\in c_{00}^*$ is given.
Since $g$ is a functional on $c_{00}$,
we can extend it to a functional $f\in c_0^*$ using the Hahn-Banach theorem.
Here, extension means that $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in c_{00}$.
This implies $F(f)=g$, and thus $F$ is surjective.